# Limited browser view when logged into report server

Tags: reporting-services, browser

When I log into our SSRS 2012 report server, the UI looks different than what others in our organization see.  I have simple hyperlinks for folders, where others have folder icons.  This seems to be the case regardless of the browser I use.

I also don't see options to, e.g., delete reports that I have created, as others do.

Our admin tells me that I have as many permissions on the server as others, and more than most.

What are the circumstances in which this more limited browser view is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What URL are you using?

servername/Reports is the website with a graphical UI.

servername/ReportServer is the web app that just lists folders and files.

Comment: Bingo.  I was using "ReportServer".